# How to make console view part of Eclipse frame

Tags: eclipse

I accidentally detached the console view from the Eclipse frame so it is now a separate window. I've been trying to figure out how to make them part of the same frame again but can't figure it out for the life of me. I searched through Eclipse help pages and couldn't find an answer either. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:
1. Find the current perspective.
2. Right click on it.
3. Click Reset.

[image]